# Several Linux distros freeze

Tags: linux, fedora, freeze, deepin

I tried to move from Windows to Linux but at the time of installation it always freezes when you enter the login password, while the mousepad is disabled, I have tried it with Mint, Ubuntu and Deepin and passed this error.

I installed Fedora and when I set the password it did not freeze, I was able to use it and it did not freeze, but when I restarted the computer it froze when I enter the password.

It should be noted that I formatted the hard disk from Linux so that it was completely blank to proceed to create the boot, swap, etc. partitions.

My computer is an Asus N580VD-DM462T notebook

Specifications of my pc:

-Core i5-7300HQ

-8GB RAM

-NVIDIA 1050 dedicated

-Toshiba 1TB HDD

Comment: `NVIDIA 1050` - that might be the issue

Comment: @UVV How do I solve it?

Comment: What password? It freezes on login?

Comment: @peterh Yes, in the login

Comment: @XDarkestX On the X11 login? Well, it seems to be really an nvidia compat problem. Google for "linux mint with opensource nvidia driver" or similar. There is a faster, closed source driver, this is included in the distributions by default, and it is a crap. You need to somehow switch to the opensource one, it is not so fast, but still useful and stable.

Comment: @XDarkestX This problem - that nearly all VGA cards of the world is nvidia, and nvidia releases shit, closed-source drivers - is currently one of the most serious problems of the Linux. [Here](https://www.golem.de/1206/92584-37796-i_rc.jpg) you can see, what is Linus Torvalds (developer of the Linux) thinking from the Nvidia.

Comment: @peterh A friend told me that possibly the motherboard is corrupted from the factory, so it only works with Windows, how true is it? And would there be any solution with some distro?

Comment: @XDarkestX Yes, that is possible, but... after I experienced a lot with nvidia / laptop vs. Linux troubles, I would estimate the probabilities so: 80% that it is an nvidia driver problem, 10% is bad hardware (it is possible that the bug happens only on Linux), 10% is that some other reason. It is not the fault of the Linux. Could you start your laptop in VESA mode?

Comment: @XDarkestX Here you can see, how can you boot a live ubuntu pendrive in vesa mode: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1584780 If it works, then the cause is surely nvidia compat.

Comment: @XDarkestX Be fast, your question will be deleted soon and I have no way to save it (all such decision requries multiple votes and I am only one).

Comment: @XDarkestX If you could get a command line on any way, here is, how can you switch to the opensource nvidia driver: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2270316 Also I dislike it, typically I am fighting with the binary nvidia driver a lot, but... newer nvidia drivers are *incompatible* with their older chips!

Comment: @XDarkestX Another example of the dirtyness of the binary nvidia driver: it replaces many part of the X Window system with its own version... the exact cause of your troubles is probably an incompatibility, not between your nvidia driver and your video chip, but between the nvidia-hacked (also binary-only) libraries and the rest of your system. Why the heck they should have hacked the base X libraries??? Probably no one can know.

Comment: @XDarkestX If you are not gaming, you absolutely don't need the binary nvidia drivers. In speed, I would say, the binary nvidia driver can in fps around 2/3 of the windows, while nouvea can only 1/3 of it, and some games don't run with it et al. But if you aren't gaming, if you are only playing with 3d google maps and so, then you absolutely don't need the nvidia binary drivers.

Comment: @peterh I need your contact, where can i contact you?

Comment: @peterh i remembered that i had already started it in VESA mode and kept presenting the same error.

Comment: @XDarkestX There are some kernel flags, maybe acpi disable?

Comment: @peterh Where do i deactivate the acpi? in my [BIOS](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/piIIfJv6-fU/maxresdefault.jpg) i have never seen it, besides it is the first time i interact with this type of BIOS.

Comment: @XDarkestX You can do it with a kernel argument. https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting